# Did I get a lemon, or does the ipod touch g4 come with a crappy usb cable?

Tags: ipod-touch, usb

Really, I mean you shell out $300 for this thing you'd think the usb cable would be able to sync after two months of use.

I ended up buying one from China that works just fine (as opposed to the one that came with it!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the new USB cable that came with my iPhone 4 was different than the older one with iPhone 3G, and even different than the one that came with my iPad. It was made with that new "rubberized" white plastic like the new ear buds, that seems springier.

Anyway, if the cable stops functioning under normal use after only two months, I'm quite certain it would be covered under Apple's iPod one year warranty. You should go to your friendly neighbourhood Apple Store or [inquire about a replacement](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/).

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that all current generation Apple devices some with the same sync cable. From my experience (almost everyone I know is an apple fan) some people wear through them pretty quickly (usually girls who wind them up and put them in hand bags etc) and some last forever (such as mine which just sits on the desk and only gets used every few days. its the original cable that came with my first iPhone a few years back and still works fine).

Answer (score 0):

I've had mine for 2 months, throwing it in the bottom of my bag every day, and I've had no problems with it yet.

It's the same thickness as the previous iPod USB cable I have, though softer.  That one is several years old and still working fine, though I haven't abused it nearly as much.

One nice thing is that, despite being Apple-proprietary, the cable itself is fairly standard across their products these days, so if you have a friend who upgrades iPods/iPhones a lot, they might have a spare (or three) they'd be willing to give you.

Also, FWIW, Apple's cable was almost certainly from China, as well.  :-)